# Положение точки относительно плоскости

Tags: геометрия

Есть тройка точек трехмерных координат(треугольник).

И есть плоскость заданная координатами точки лежащей на плоскости и ее нормалью.

Как узнать какие точки треугольника левее-правее или выше-ниже плоскости? И расстояние от точки к плоскости.

Буду благодарен за разъяснение вопроса!

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Положение точки относительно плоскости можно определить по **знаку** скалярного произведения вектора нормали и вектора базовая точка плоскости-данная точка

```
(P-Base).dot.n
```

Если знак положительный, то точка лежит с той стороны, куда "смотрит" нормаль. Понятия "левее-правее или выше-ниже" не всегда применимы.

Из нормализованного вектора нормали и базовой точки можно получить уравнение плоскости

```
nx*x + ny*y + nz*z + d = 0
```

подставив в него координаты базовой точки и найдя `d`

Если же в уравнение подставить координаты данной точки, то получим знаковое расстояние от точки до плоскости ([формула 6](https://matworld.ru/analytic-geometry/rasstojanie-tochka-ploskost-online.php)). Смысл знака - как и раньше.

```
dist = abs(nx*px + ny*py + nz*pz + d)
side = sign(nx*px + ny*py + nz*pz + d)
```